# Centrar elemento com bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-3

Colegas. Tenho o código abaixo, porém não estou conseguindo centralizar o formulário. Estou usando a última versão do Bootstrap. Já tentei colocar align="center", mas também não funcionou. Vejam:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5" style="margin: 20px">            
                  <form method="post">
                              <label>Faça seu acesso abaixo:</label>
                              <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Login">
                              </div>
                              <div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 10px">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                                <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Senha">
                              </div>
                              <div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 10px">
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Acessar</button>
                              </div>
              </form>
               </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está nesta linha:

```
<div class="col-md-5" style="margin: 20px">
```

Para centrar usando só bootstrap use offset `col-X-offset-Y`. Mude para:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4" style="margin-top: 20px">
```

Também havia um conflito entre a sua `margin` e a `margin` da classe `col-sm-offset-X` do bootstrap, se for só a `margin-top` que quer, pode fazer desta maneira

Comment: Perfeito Miguel. Obrigado.

Comment: De nada @Fox.11.